# How to create a form with Date input field by Strut's Taglib?

Tags: struts-1

How can I create a form with a date field using `taglib` of `Struts 1.3`?

I want to simulate the `type = "date"` of HTML5 to insert a born date of a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any "date" struts tag.

You just have to use `<html:text>` and convert them to dates.

[Link to Struts html tag docs](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.3.x/struts-taglib/tlddoc/html/tld-summary.html)